# Expo does not show the current app I'm working on

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have just started learning React Native and I'm using Expo : npm start to see my code on my phone, but so far, whenever I try to do it, it keeps showing me an old app I have been working on.  I have tried refreshing, deleting the cache, turning off and on laptop, phone, and still nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using git? If yes, you should checkout the branch of your current branch, if you're in different directory maybe you should check your directory, and run `expo start`

Comment: remove the app from Expo client

Comment: i removed it, but still doesnt work...

Comment: im not using git, Im editting my code in Atom and using Anaconda prompt.  From Anaconda I go to the projects' directory and run npm start or expo start